# Powershell XML add key value as element

Tags: xml, powershell

**Objective**: Save xml as csv

**Problem**: required data is contained within key

**Example code**:

`[xml] $sample = '<TestTop><TestElements><td field="head.office">ABC</td><td field="head.number">101</td><td field="head.colour">Blue</td><key><office>ABC</office><number>101</number><line>1</line></key></TestElements><TestElements><td field="head.office">ABC</td><td field="head.number">102</td><td field="head.colour">Red</td><key><office>ABC</office><number>102</number><line>2</line></key></TestElements></TestTop>'`

**Execute**: `$sample.TestTop.ChildNodes.td`

**Returns**:

```
field       #text
-----       -----
head.office ABC  
head.number 101  
head.colour Blue 
head.office ABC  
head.number 102  
head.colour Red
```

**Execute**: $sample.TestTop.ChildNodes.key

**Returns**:

```
office number line
------ ------ ----
ABC    101    1   
ABC    102    2
```

**Desired result**: csv output with *key*.**line** appended to element results i.e.

```
field       #text
-----       -----
head.office ABC    
head.number 101  
head.colour Blue
line        1
head.office ABC  
head.number 102  
head.colour Red
line        2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do top-level [member-access enumeration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_member-access_enumeration?view=powershell-7.2) with `$sample.TestTop.ChildNodes.td` because you want to interleave `td` rows with their corresponding `line = ...` rows, so you'll need to iterate over the `TestElements` nodes yourself...

```
[xml] $sample = @"
<TestTop>
  <TestElements>
    <td field="head.office">ABC</td>
    <td field="head.number">101</td>
    <td field="head.colour">Blue</td>
    <key>
      <office>ABC</office>
      <number>101</number>
      <line>1</line>
    </key>
  </TestElements>
  <TestElements>
    <td field="head.office">ABC</td>
    <td field="head.number">102</td>
    <td field="head.colour">Red</td>
    <key>
      <office>ABC</office>
      <number>102</number>
      <line>2</line>
    </key>
  </TestElements>
</TestTop>
"@

$data = $sample.TestTop.TestElements | foreach-object {
   $_.td | foreach-object { [pscustomobject] [ordered] @{ "field"=$_.field; "#text"=$_.InnerText } }
   [pscustomobject] [ordered] @{ "field"="line"; "#text"=$_.key.line }
}

$data
# field       #text
# -----       -----
# head.office ABC
# head.number 101
# head.colour Blue
# line        1
# head.office ABC
# head.number 102
# head.colour Red
# line        2

$data | export-csv "myfile.csv"
```